# Angular does not update "input property" when * gnFor adds new item from an observable

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2

I have two components **home.component.ts** and its child **like-review.component.ts** I send a couple of params through input binding to **like.component.ts** when a new transmission arrives from firebase input binding Angular does not update and it send params of last item transmitted, for update I have to refresh page and its params sends correctly.

**home.component.html**

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let card of cards | async;trackBy:trackByFn; let i = index">
  ....
  
      <like-review [card]="card" [userId]="uid"></like-review>


  ...
</ng-container>
```

**like-review.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'like-review',
  templateUrl: 'like-review.html'
})
export class LikeReviewComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked, AfterContentInit {

  @Input() userId;
  @Input() card: Card;

  likesObservable: Observable<any>;


 .....
}
  ngOnInit() {
 
     
    this.likesObservable = this.fav.getUserLike(this.userId, this.card.id).map(data => {
      if(data == null) {
        return false;
      }else{
        return data.like;
      }
    });



  }


.....

}
```

I retrive input propietys on ngOninit() life hook works fine if in home.components.html does not send new transmition of items but when new items arrives like-review send last item added and and not the new one.

Any help it's apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix it, In child call firebase reference  from ngOnChanges or an input setter

```js
  @Input() card: Card;

get mycard(): Card {

  return this.card;

}


ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  console.log('valor anterior', changes.card.previousValue);
  console.log('valor valor actual.', changes.card.currentValue);
  debugger
  this.likesObservable = this.fav.getUserLike(this.userId, this.mycard.id).map(data => {
    if(data == null) {
      return false;
    }else{
      return data.like;
    }
  });
  
}
```